# AppService VNet integration fails

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I need to access a VM using an AppService. I'm getting this when i try to integrate with the VNET.
[image]

It just says VNet configuration failed and nothing more. AppService plan is in Premium.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could scale up the app service plan to Standard or Premium V2. There are [some limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration) with using VNet Integration with VNets in the same region:

> The feature is available from all App Service scale units **in Premium
> V2 and Premium V3**. It is **also available in Standard but only from
> newer App Service scale units**. If you are on an older scale unit you
> can only use the feature from a Premium V2 App Service plan. If you
> want to be certain of being able to use the feature in a Standard App
> Service plan, create your app in a Premium V3 App Service plan. Those
> plans are only supported on our newest scale units. You can scale down
> if you desire after that.

Comment: Just upgraded my app service plan to P3V3. still the same. any idea?

Comment: Do you verify the other limitations in my shared [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration)?

Comment: We have made few configuration mistakes. This was very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Which mistakes were that? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Likewise, having the same issue. Scaling down from P1V3 didn't seem to solve the issue.